# how to extend a method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add additional functionality to a method, for instance:

```
console.log()
```

so the original 'log' functionality is retained, and I can get it to do something new as well. Is this possible? I've read a few bits on using prototype but haven't quite grasped it.

Many thanks,

Comment: Think of it like this: you can ADD something to OBJECT, but cannot ALTER what already EXISTS. You can add log2() to console object, but cannot modify already existing log().

Comment: [fcombine](https://github.com/Raynos/fcombine) allows you to combine functions and returns a new one.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy. If you want your new `log` mehod to be in place of the old `log` method just do something like that:

```
console._log = console.log; // just backing up old log method
console.log = function(){
    console._log(arguments);
    alert("I'm doing something else here");     
}
console.log(console);
```

---

UPDATE:

All the solutions presented, including mine, didn't reproduced the log behavior perfectly as @TomBates stated. The output differed because arguments were being logged wrapped in an object instead of passed separately. The only way I could find to reproduce the behavior of the old log + the extending functionality was doing this:

```
    console.log(window, this, console); // old log in action

console._log = console.log; // just backing up old log method
console.log = function(){
    var args_string = '';
    for(i in arguments){
        if(arguments.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            args_string += 'arguments['+ i + ']';
            if(i != arguments.length - 1){
                args_string += ',';
            } 
        }
    }
    var expression = 'console._log(' + args_string + ');';
    eval(expression);

    alert("I'm doing something else here"); 
    // your dazzling method extension here   
}

console.log(window, this, console); //new log in action
```

Not so elegant, but works as expected. the outputs of both old log and new log are now identical.

Comment: corrected, added argument to the new console method too so it becomes as useful as the 'old' one

Comment: You just broke `console.log.length`

Comment: I guess the console.log.length is necessary to be intact for some test suits to work as expected, so it seems important to leave it as it is, like @Deeptechtons cleverly did in his answer too.

Comment: Thanks for the answers all. @marcioAlmada: this solution almost works, though the original behaviour is different. For instance if you log a jquery element before / after using this solution, you'll see a difference in the log behaviour. (Either Firebug or Web Inspector on Webkit)

Comment: Yep, that's because the  `arguments` object is wrapping the function arguments and this interfere in the log output. Take a look at the updated answer, it has a new better solution (less elegant).

Answer (score 1):

as javascript is callable oriented, you could do:

```
console._log_without_my_extension = console.log
console.log = function() { console._log_without_my_extension(); .... }
```

for example.

Comment: your console._log_without_my_extension() needs to receive a parameter to still be useful.

Comment: yes, of course he needs to receive and carry over any parameters he needs!

Answer (score 0):

Extending in JS is not a default functionality as far as I know the only way is something like the following:

```
var oldLog = console.log;
console.log = function(){
    //doStuff
    oldLog(arguments);
    //doStuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prototype` property only when objects already have them. `console` is not one of them. Use other answers for this. And read this to learn about `prototype`:

http://phrogz.net/js/classes/ExtendingJavaScriptObjectsAndClasses.html

By the way: there is no way to extend functions unless you make a wrapper, just like suggested in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

If you are strictly trying to extend the console in Firebug it doesn't have a prototype, so you will be fine doing this

```
console.logMe = function(){console.log(arguments)};
console.logMe("welcome to SO");
```

#### Update

Since i had understood the question wrong manner i would like to correct it. The OP wanted to abstract the base method away and override the base method.(Seems like i am talking rubbish, look into code below)

```
function myConsole() {}

myConsole.prototype = {
    _log: console.log,
    Log: function () {
        this._log(arguments)
    }
};
```

with all other methods you will have to do it again and again. But here every instance you create will have the extended method and your very own inbuilt implementation.

#### Usage

```
var x = new myConsole();
x.Log("Hi this is Deeptechtons");
```

Comment: @Everyone who downvoted, it would be nice to know the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Was not me, but the question was to extend a method, not create a new one.

Comment: I downvoted it, but s%it, your code is ok and I evaluated it wrong! (looked too quickly and thought it had the same error another answer had). Tried to undo the vote but app says I can't undo my downvote unless the answer is edited (too much time passed). Could you make a minor edit so I can undo my downvote?? I'm really sorry for that.